# Use RewriteMap against a cookie value with RewriteRule

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, cookies, escaping

I am trying to escape a cookie value that is being set by RewriteRule.

For example, say my site is http://www.example.com/blah/foo%2Bbar

I need to take part of the URL and send it back as a cookie.

In this case, I can see the url being unescaped by Apache.

What comes back from the browser is:

`Set-Cookie:mycookie=foo+bar; path=/; domain=www.example.com`

This is my current config (note I added the escape RewriteMap to attempt to resolve my issue, but it doesnt do anything):

```
RewriteMap esc int:escape

RewriteRule /blah/(.*) - [co=mycookie:${esc:$1}:www.example.com,L]
```

What I need from the response is:

`Set-Cookie:mycookie=foo%2Bbar; path=/; domain=www.example.com`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this via a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use URI::Escape;
$| = 1;
while (<STDIN>) {
  my $a = $_;
  chomp($a);
  $a = uri_escape($a);
  $a =~ s/%2F/\//g;
  print "$a\n";
}
```

This is my new config:

```
RewriteMap encode-map prg:/var/www/encode.pl
RewriteRule /blah/(.*) - [co=mycookie:${encode-map:$1}:www.example.com,L]
```

I was able to borrow the implementation idea from: [RewriteRule, RewriteMap that sets Cookie work badly together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252862/rewriterule-rewritemap-that-sets-cookie-work-badly-together?rq=1)

This does the trick.